# PHP: cURL refuse connection to URL and send GET information on some server

Tags: php, curl, geolocation, cross-domain

I made function to read GeoPlugin data for my websites and on one server I find wierd issue. All cURL request are refused. Here is part of my code:

```
protected $url='http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={IP}&base_currency={CURRENCY}';

protected function __get_data($ip=false, $currency='')
    {
        // Current or custom IP
        $ip = ((is_bool($ip) && $ip==false) ? $this->__ip() : $ip);
        if($ip!='127.0.0.1' || $ip!='0.0.0.0')
        {
            // Configure GET function
            $url = str_replace('{IP}', $ip, $this->url );
            if(empty($currency))
                $url = str_replace( '&base_currency={CURRENCY}', '', $url);
            else
                $url = str_replace( '{CURRENCY}', $currency, $url);
            // Get content from URL
            if(function_exists("curl_init"))
            {
                $cURL = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); 
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 2);
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
                $result = curl_exec($cURL);
                curl_close($cURL);
            }
            else
            {
                $result = file_get_contents($url);
            }
            // Return objects from JSON data
            if($result!=false)
            {
                return json_decode($result);
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    ## find real IP adress of visitor ##
    protected function __ip()
    {
        $findIP=array(
            'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
            'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
            'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_FORWARDED',
            'REMOTE_ADDR'
        );
        $ip = '';
        foreach($findIP as $http)
        {
            if(function_exists("getenv"))
            {
                $ip = getenv($http);
            }
            else
            {
                if (array_key_exists($http, $_SERVER) !== false){
                    foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$http]) as $findIP){
                        $ip = trim($findIP);

                    }
                }
            }
            if(function_exists("filter_var") && !empty($ip))
            {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false) return $ip;

            }
            else if(preg_match('/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/', $ip) && !empty($ip))
            {
                return $ip;
            }
        }
        return '0.0.0.0';
    }
```

On arround90 websites everithing work perfectly, on one website with `var_dump()` I find that connection are refused. I try also with `file_get_contents` and the same results. I try also just cURL call in some test PHP file separated from website and the same results. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's may be DNS problem;
2. It's may be poor connection (more time needed for loading);
3. Your query may be banned from target server, because from your IP (source's server IP) too much queries for a time, more than limits.

What you can do:

1. Make sure that you can open target url from source server without using cURL (if you use simple hosting, I mean not VPS, you'll can't check it);
2. Increase values for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT;
3. If problem will not solved, you should use proxy with cURL (look for official documentation about CURLOPT_PROXY and other proxy options for curl_setopt function).

Comment: DNS or server banned IP can make a sense. Timeout is not a problem, that is first what I check. But I try to call something else and find the same problem. Or banned IP or DNS. How to checkthat? What inside DNS can made that?

Comment: If your server has DNS problem and you have access to DNS properties, you may change address of DNS server. As example, you may use Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4, it's free. If problem will not solved, this would mean that your IP banned. If you haven't access to DNS properties or you sure that IP banned, you need use proxy in cURL.

Comment: Yeah, proxy can be good solution. I will try that first, I don't have access to DNS.

Answer (score 0):

cURL might be disabled in your server.

Please run the phpinfo() to check the status of cURL.

If it is disabled, please install cURL and enable it in PHP.

Comment: cURL is enabled, also not work with file_get_contents